# Problema básico de programación en números decimales con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema básico de programación PHP en el siguiente código.

```
<?php
$x = 0.1;
for ($i= 1; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    if ($x == 0.1 or $x == 0.5 or $x == 0.9){
        $x = $x + 0.2;
        echo $x ." ";
    }
    else $x = $x + 0.1;
}?>
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
0.3 0.7
```

Mi pregunta es, no debería salir:

```
0.3 0.7 1.1
```

Lo curioso es que con ese mismo código con números enteros obtengo el resultado esperado equivalente. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que lo principal es que expliques lo que intentas hacer, pues tu código hace lo que hace, no puede hacer otra cosa distinta si no se lo indicas. Por ejemplo, `0.5` no puede salir, porque es parte de la comparación y antes del `echo` modificas el valor de `$x`, de modo que `0.5` nunca se imprimirá.

Comment: Qué es lo que esperas recibir? `0.3 0.5 y 0.11`? porque 0.5 no saldría ya que es parte de la comparación donde sumas no?

Comment: No porque cuando es 0.5 le sumas 0.2 y luego imprimes 0.7

Comment: Toda la razón. Disculpad, ya lo he corregido. Lo del 0.5 ha sido un error quería decir 0.7. En cuanto al 0.11 porque no me sale??

Comment: Estoy redactando la respuesta, encontré que sucede, por cierto, el 0.11 no existe, seguiría 1.1 jaja

Answer (score 3):

el problema surge dado el punto flotante, algo muy común en casi todos los lenguajes de programación.

```php
$x = 8 - 6.4;  // que es igual a 1.6
$y = 1.6;
var_dump($x == $y); // No es true

//PHP piensa que 1.6 (proveniente de una diferencia) no es igual a 1.6. Para que funcione debemos usar round()

var_dump(round($x, 2) == round($y, 2)); // Esto es true

//Esto sucede probablemente porque $x no es realmente 1.6, sino 1.599999.. y var_dump te lo muestra como 1.6.
```

Más info acá:

- [Números de punto flotante ¶](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.float.php)
- [PHP - Floating Number Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-floating-number-precision)

La solución a tu problema es esta, con el siguiente código se obtiene el resultado deseado.
En la comparación, en mi caso lo hice con un switch pero funciona igual si quieres hacerlo con el if, solo usa el `round($x, 2)` para redondear tu variable.

```php
<?php
$x = 0.1;
for ($i= 1; $i <= 9; ++$i) {    
    switch (round($x, 2)) {
        case 0.1:
        case 0.5:
        case 0.9:
            $x += 0.2;
            echo $x ." <br>";   
            break;
        default:
            $x += 0.1;
            break;
    }
    
}
?>
```

> PD: Recuerda que 0.11 no aparecerá, ya que si sumas 0.2 a 0.9 dará
> como resultado 1.1.

Espero resuelva tu pregunta.

Para mucha más info sobre el problema del punto flotante visita https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Allí se trata el curioso caso de `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`

Comment: Lo primero, muchísimas gracias por tu contestación Fabian Montoya, aparte de que me has solucionado un problema que llevaba mucho tiempo intentando solucionar, me parece que tu respuesta es muy elaborada y clara. Lo segundo es que una vez más tienes razón, sería 1.1 no 0.11, y es que en el código original tenía otros números y para ponerlo más claro puse esos, de ahí mi error al escribirlos...