# Hacer operaciones matemáticas exactas en php

Tags: php

Hola quisiera saber si hay alguna librería o alguna forma de hacer operaciones en php sin errores, porque cuando hago una multiplicación simple de por ejemplo 3*2.5 me devuelve 7.499999999000992, o cuando transformo un string en float pasa lo mismo, entonces quiero saber cómo realizar operaciones de manera exacta, sin usar round porque no me sirve, necesito hacer operaciones delicadas, encontré decimal.js que permite hacer operaciones exactas en javascript, quiero algo así pero para php.

Comment: Intenta esta: https://php-decimal.io/#introduction

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/405931/6798)

Answer (score 0):

Este es un problema típico de los nº en punto/coma flotante en todos los lenguajes, ya que la precisión no es infinita. Para el ejemplo que propones, en realidad debería darte 7.5, pero tarde o temprano te encontrarás con alguna cosa rara.

Para esos casos, considera hacer redondeos con la función `round(numero, cifrasDecimales)`

Por ejemplo `round(3*2.5, 2);`  debería redondearte a 7.5.

Echa un ojo a la documentación de [round](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.round.php)

### Precisión infinita

Existen formas de trabajar con precisión exacta (infinita, arbitraria). Esto es básicamente usando string para representar los números y usando funciones que hacen operaciones con dichas strings como [bcadd](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.bcadd.php). Te advierto que estas funciones son, por supuesto, más pesadas. Puede que no sea lo que necesites.